# Kubernetes nginx ingress not accessing external API

Tags: java, azure, kubernetes, devops

Im tring to access a external API from my service (site-api) in kubernetes, this external API can only be accessed with IP Whitelist, so i gave the IP of my ingress (EXTERNAL IP), this ip is located in kubernetes dashboard (Discovery and Load Balancing / Ingresses), but i still get access denied, the ip which i have to provide is correct? it is missing some settings in ingress yaml ?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: site-name
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "15m"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - site-name
    secretName: aks-ingress-tls
  rules:
  - host: site-name
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /?(.*) 
        backend:
          serviceName: site-web
          servicePort: 443
      - path: /message/?(.*) 
        backend:
          serviceName: site-message
          servicePort: 3001
      - path: /api/?(.*) 
        backend:
          serviceName: site-api
          servicePort: 8443
```

Answer (score 0):

•   The IP shown in the dashboard on Discovery and Load Balancing/Ingress is not the IP address that is to be whitelisted. Instead, the service object(site-api) that is trying to access the external IP will expose the deployment as well as the external IP that needs to be whitelisted.

•   So, first create a service object that exposes the deployment of the site-api and display information about that service object that is created for exposing the deployment.

•   Once, we get the concise information about the service object, get the detailed information about that service object which will display the detailed information about the external IP that the site-api is trying to access.

•   So, the external IP address will be exposed by this service object which will need to be whitelisted. Also, take a note of the endpoint IP addresses and their ports which are accessing the site-api through the ports and node ports. You can then access the site-api service using the external IP address and the port in the displayed information.

•   Please find the below Kubernetes commands to execute the steps as above: -

```
kubectl expose deployment<site-api>--type=LoadBalancer --name=my-service  Service object creation for exposing the deployment

kubectl get services my-service  Display information about the service

kubectl describe services my-service  Display detailed information about the service

kubectl get pods --output=wide  Get endpoint information

curl http://<external-ip>:<port>  Access the site-api through external IP
```

Please refer the below link for more information: -

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/